# Why are not all type information erased in Java at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

My obviously wrong understanding of Java Generics was up to now, that Type Erasure removes all type information such that there is nothing left at all at runtime. Recently I stumbled upon a code fragment where I had to ask myself: How the hack does this work? Simplified, it presents as:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public abstract class SuperClass<T> {

    private final Type type;

    protected SuperClass(){
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType =
                (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        type = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void tellMyType(){
        System.out.println("Hi, my type parameter is " + type);
    }    
}
```

and

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass sc = new SuperClass<Integer>(){};
        sc.tellMyType();
    }
}
```

Executing the Main Class results in `Hi, my type parameter is class java.lang.Integer`.

What we can see here is, that the type information of T is also available at runtime, which contradicts my initial understanding.

So my question is: Why does the compiler keep this? Is this required for some internal JVM behavior or is there any reasonable explanation for this effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860:

> It turns out that while the JVM will
>   not track the actual type arguments
>   for instances of a generic class, it
>   does track the actual type arguments
>   for subclasses of generic classes. In
>   other words, while a new
>   `ArrayList<String>()` is really just a
>   new `ArrayList()` at runtime, if a class
>   extends `ArrayList<String>`, then the
>   JVM knows that `String` is the actual
>   type argument for `List`'s type
>   parameter.

In your case, you are making an anonymous subclass of the parameterized type, so the type information is retained.  See the article for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Short remark: if your subclass simply passes the generic type (as in `public class SuperList<T> extends ArrayList<T>`), the output of the example code (without any anonymous classes involved) would be "Hi, my type parameter is T"

Comment: So if they had left out the `{}` in `main` (which would probably require changing the constructor to public), then the fact that the type parameter was `Integer` would have been lost at runtime?

Answer (score 19):

Type parameters are being erased only from the dynamic types (i.e. a type of object being created):

```
Object o = new ArrayList<String>(); // String erased
```

It's retained in static types (i.e. field, argument and return types, `throws` clause, superclass and superinterface declarations):

```
class Test implements Superclass<String> { // String retained 
    // Accessible via Class.getGenericSuperclass()

    private List<Integer> l; // Integer retained (via Field.getGenericType())

    public void test(List<Long> l) {} // Long retained (via Method.getGenericParameterTypes())

    // Character retained (via Method.getGenericReturnType())
    public List<Character> test() { return null; }
}
```

In your case, you create an anonymous subclass of `SuperClass<Integer>`, so type parameter is retained in the superclass declaration.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) uses this to create [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)s to represent generic classes at runtime.  For example

```
TypeLiteral<List<String>> list = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
```

can be used, but

```
Class<List<String>> list = List<String>.class;
```

won't compile.

The technique is known as a 'super type token' (see [Neal Gafter's article](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) on the subject).

Answer (score 2):

[This FAQ on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure) might help.

Comment: Did you check whether it does?

Comment: How can I know if it helps Lars?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get ParameterizedType to work for me (I couldn't change the code of SuperClass). However, the following simple code worked fine:

```
try
    {
    SuperClass<Integer> castSc = (SuperClass<Integer>)sc;
    // Do what you want to do if generic type is Integer...
    }
catch (ClassCastException ignored)
    {
    }
```