# Java :: obtaining parameterized type names at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

The following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ParameterizedType apType = (ParameterizedType) li.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Type[] typeArguments = apType.getActualTypeArguments();
    int _i = 0;
    for (Type type : typeArguments) {
        System.out.format("parameterized type %d is: %s", ++_i, type);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
parameterized type 1 is: E
```

1. Do I understand correctly that this is because of the effects of Type Erasure and that it should be interpreted as "unknown", given that **E** is the type parameter name?
2. It strikes me as odd that I somehow have to interpret the name "E" (and I suppose "S", "U", etc. if more exist) specially. What if I have a class "E"? Moreover the method name is get_**Actual**_TypeArguments. Given that type parameters serve as placeholders much like variables I find it very odd that a method should return the name of the *variable*. Am I missing something here?
3. Also, it's not clear to me why I can cast the superclass to **ParameterizedType** but not the class itself. Trying to cast the result of **li.getClass()** as a **ParameterizedType** yields the following compile time error:

   required: ParameterizedType
   found:    Class
             where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
                CAP#1 extends List from capture of ? extends List

I've seen this [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296299/accessing-parameterized-type-information-at-runtime) but it hasn't enlightened me.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657542/how-to-use-java-reflection-to-check-a-given-class-is-implements-iterable-exten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All instances of a generic class share the same runtime class:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass() == new ArrayList<String>().getClass()
```

Put differently, the runtime does not track the actual type arguments used to instantiate a generic class. However, it does know the types declared in the source code, and that's what getGenericSuperclass() and friends return. So if you have a class:

```
class Environment extends HashMap<String, Object> {

}
```

The expression

```
new Environment().getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

returns

```
java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
```

In contrast, if you declare

```
class Environment<E> extends HashMap<String, E> {
}
```

the same expression returns

```
java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, E>
```

So yes, getGenericSuperclass returns the actual type parameters as declared in the source code, but those type parameters may contain type variables declared elsewhere.

> Also, it's not clear to me why I can cast the superclass to **ParameterizedType** but not the class itself.

A `ParametrizedType` object represents a compile time type with a non-empty list of type arguments, a `Class` object a runtime type (which doesn't have any type arguments). Therefore, a `Class` is not a `ParametrizedType`.

Comment: Re the last point, it is not intuitively obvious to me why, given an object handle, I can get the type arguments of its superclass, but not of its class.

Comment: Because a class declaration contains type *parameters* for the class itself, but type *arguments* for its super class.