# Type parameter on Generic class Java

Tags: java, generics

Type erasure is the process of removing generic information for backward compatibility on compiled class.
Then, I can't know what type of class are the objects in a generic class, but in an inherited class, for example:

```
package generics.testing;

class Box<T> {
    private T value;

    public Box() {
        System.out.println("GenericSuperClass: " + getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class IntegerBox extends Box<Integer> {}

public class GenericsTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<String> box = new Box<>();
        IntegerBox ibox = new IntegerBox();
    }
}
```

I get:

```
GenericSuperClass: class java.lang.Object
GenericSuperClass: generics.testing.Box<java.lang.Integer>
```

My question is, why is that information `generics.testing.Box<java.lang.Integer>` preserved and where is stored?

Comment: You might find that interesting read: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained (specifically part about TypeToken implementation)

Comment: It is stored into your class itself as it is part of its declaration, simply launch javap generics.testing.IntegerBox, you will see it appear

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320658/why-are-not-all-type-information-erased-in-java-at-runtime