# Using 'diamond' notation for methods in java

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I'm currently working on a component-based architecture management system in java. My current implementation of the retrieval of a component attached to an object works like this:

```java
// ...

private final HashMap<Class<? extends EntityComponent>, EntityComponent> components;

// ...

public <T extends EntityComponent> T getComponent(Class<T> component)
  {
    // ... some sanity checks
    if (!this.hasComponent(component))
    {
        // ... some exception handling stuff
    }

    return component.cast(this.components.get(component));
  }

// ...
```

Now, this works fine, but it somewhat bugs me to have to write

```java
object.getComponent(SomeComponent.class)
```

everytime I need to access a component.
Would it be possible to utilize generics in a way to shift the syntax to something more along the lines of

```java
object.getComponent<SomeComponent>()
```

, utilizing the diamond operator to specify the class, instead of passing the class of the component as a parameter to the method?
I know it's not really a big thing, but making the syntax of often used code as pretty / compact as possible goes a long way I guess.

Comment: No, this is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, since type-parameters are "erased" in Java. That means that they are only available at compile-time (where the compiler is using them to type-check the code), but not at run-time.

So when your code is running, the `<SomeComponent>` type-parameter no longer exists, and your code therefore can't do any operations (if/else, etc) based on its value.

In other words:

- At compile time, your method call looks like this: `object.getComponent<SomeComponent>()`
- But after compilation your method call just looks like this `object.getComponent()`. There is no type-parameter any more.

So, yes, unfortunately you still need to pass a `Class` object along, or something similar (see "Super Type Tokens" for example), if you need to do something that depends on the type parameter at run-time.

The reason the `Class` workaround works is that it loosely speaking represents the type-parameter, since the type-checker makes sure that its instance fits with the type-parameter, but is an object and thus available at run-time too - unlike the type-parameter.

Note: The `Class`-trick doesn't work for type-parameters within type-parameters, such as `Class<List<Something>>`, since at run-time `List<Something>` and `List<OtherThing>` is the same class, namely `List`. So you can't make a `Class` token to differentiate between those two types. As far as i remember "Super Type Tokens" can be used instead to fix this (they exploit the fact that there is an exception to erasure: For subclasses of generic classes, the type-parameters used when "extending" the superclass are actually available at run-time through reflection. (there are also more exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320725/1743225)).

*(Related google terms: "Erasure", "Reification", "Reified generics")*

Comment: Seems like I'll have to keep using the parameter approach then. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!